# Setting multiple propertyToSearch to search from

Tags: jquery, jquery-tokeninput

using jQuery's plugin tokenInput I've set my propertyToSearch: "name"

But I would also like to search on another field like this:

```
propertyToSearch: "name,email"
```

or

```
propertyToSearch: ["name","email"]
```

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do it without changing the core of plugin in jQuery-tokeninput.js.
Basically you need to split propertyToSearch on two places and do some stuff for each found property.

Example what I did (around line 924):

```
                    var this_li;

                if($(input).data("settings").propertyToSearch.indexOf(',') > -1){
                    var propertiesToSearch = $(input).data("settings").propertyToSearch.split(',');
                }

                if(typeof propertiesToSearch != 'undefined' && propertiesToSearch.length > 0){
                    this_li = $(input).data("settings").resultsFormatter(value);
                    $.each(propertiesToSearch, function(index, property){                           
                        this_li = find_value_and_highlight_term(this_li ,value[property], query);
                    });
                    this_li = $(this_li).appendTo(dropdown_ul);
                }
                else{
                    this_li = $(input).data("settings").resultsFormatter(value);
                    this_li = find_value_and_highlight_term(this_li ,value[$(input).data("settings").propertyToSearch], query);
                    this_li = $(this_li).appendTo(dropdown_ul);
                }
```

And similar change around line 1091:

```
                    // Do the search through local data
                var results = $.grep($(input).data("settings").local_data, function (row) {

                    if($(input).data("settings").propertyToSearch.indexOf(',') > -1){
                        var propertiesToSearch = $(input).data("settings").propertyToSearch.split(',');
                    }
                    if(typeof propertiesToSearch != 'undefined' && propertiesToSearch.length > 0){
                        var status = false;
                        $.each(propertiesToSearch, function(key, value){
                            if(row[value].toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1){
                                status = true;
                            }
                        });

                        return status;
                    }
                    else{
                        return row[$(input).data("settings").propertyToSearch].toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1; 
                    }                        
                });
```